# uninitialized constant Recipe::CategoryId

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm trying to add categories to each recipe. The user selects the category via a form. I am getting a uninitialized constant Recipe::CategoryId error, does anybody know whatsup?

recipe model:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :description, :nickname, :title, :ingredients, :instructions, :category_ids, presence: true

   has_many :category_ids
end
```

category model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipes
end
```

recipes controller:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all
  end

  def show
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new

  end

  def edit
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)

    if @recipe.save
      redirect_to recipes_url
    else
      render:new
  end
end

def update
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])

    if @recipe.update_attributes(recipe_params)
      redirect_to recipe_path(@recipe)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    @recipe.destroy
    redirect_to recipes_path
  end

  private
  def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:nickname, :website, :instagram, :title, :description, :instructions, :ingredients, :notes, :embed, :photo, :category_ids)
  end

end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>

 <% if @recipe.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@recipe.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this recipe from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :nickname %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :nickname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :website %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :website %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :instagram %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :instagram %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :ingredients %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :ingredients %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :instructions %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :instructions %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :notes %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :notes %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :embed %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :embed %>
  </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :photo %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :photo %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">

<%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name %>

</div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

recipe migration:

```
class CreateRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :recipes do |t|
    t.string   :nickname
    t.string   :website
    t.string   :instagram
    t.string   :title
    t.string   :description
    t.string   :ingredients
    t.string   :instructions
    t.string   :notes
    t.string   :embed
    t.string   :photo

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

categories:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150722174136) do

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end



  create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "nickname"
    t.string   "website"
    t.string   "instagram"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "ingredients"
    t.string   "instructions"
    t.string   "notes"
    t.string   "embed"
    t.string   "photo"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: this `has_many :category_ids` should be `has_many :categories` validation should also be on categories rather than category_ids

Comment: And also `belongs_to :recipes` should be `belongs_to :recipe`.

Comment: Thanks guys! except now I get this error:  error prohibited this recipe from being saved:

Categories can't be blank ... why is it saying its blank if i selected it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a many to many relationship between recipes and categories, first create a many to many dummy join table as follow:

```
create_table "categories_recipes" do |t|
    t.integer   "recipe_id"
    t.integer   "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Then add associations.

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :description, :nickname, :title, :ingredients, :instructions, :category_ids, presence: true

   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

You need to add it to Category Model as well

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  #other stuffs
  has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes
end
```

Comment: thank you! now i get this error: Could not find table 'categories_recipes' ... should i create the table? if so what should i put inside?